# Parsing Table With Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, parsing, selenium, beautifulsoup

Im writing a program that goes to my school grades site and takes my grades and makes them my desktop background but once i get to my grades i cant get how to parse them out of the large table

Here is my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://ps.rsd.edu/public/")

elem = driver.find_element_by_name("account")
elem.send_keys("Username")
elem2 = driver.find_element_by_name("pw")
elem2.send_keys("Password")
elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
print soup
driver.quit()

print "done"
```

this prints the source for the page but i want to get the grades out of a row called S2 
sorry its kinda hard because i cant show you the actual site

here are all the names of the rows in the table:

```
<table class="grid">
<tr><th class="center" colspan="25">Attendance By Class</th></tr>
<tr class="center th2">
<th rowspan="2">Exp</th>
<th colspan="5">Last Week</th><th colspan="5">This Week</th><th rowspan="2">Course</th>
<th rowspan="2">Q1</th>
<th rowspan="2">Q2</th>
<th rowspan="2">S1</th>
<th rowspan="2">Q3</th>
<th rowspan="2">Q4</th>
<th rowspan="2">S2</th>
<th rowspan="2">Absences</th>
<th rowspan="2">Tardies</th>
</tr>
```

and this is an example row:

```
<a href="scores.html?  frn=004711281&begdate=01/23/2013&enddate=06/07/2013&fg=S2">B<br>84</a></td>
<td><a
```

Comment: its alot of code ill try to get the relevant part

Comment: this is the whole table https://gist.github.com/C-Dubb/5522909

Comment: just the numbers from semester 2 thats it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This resource might help you: [locating elements in selenium](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/locating-elements.html)

you might try using

```
find_element_by_link_text
```

and the name of one of your courses to obtain an element containing the grades for that course